# Throw message not being shown

Tags: powershell, error-handling, adsi

I'm trying to print my own error messages using `throw`. Consider this example:

```
$computerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$adsi = [adsi]("WinNT://$computerName")

if (!($adsi.Children.Find($userGroup, 'group')))
{ 
    throw "User group not found."
}
```

If the user group is incorrect, this error message is shown:

`Exception calling "Find" with "2" argument(s): The group name could not be found.`

Is there a way to show my `throw` message, rather than the generic exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$computerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$adsi = [adsi]("WinNT://$computerName")
try {
    $adsi.Children.Find($userGroup, 'group')
}
catch{ 
    throw "User group not found."
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`[adsi]` has a habit of throwing terminating errors. This happens with `Get-ADUser` as well. This is why capturing the error in a `try`/`catch` (like in [whatever's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46931134/3829407)) is necessary.

As an alternative you can check if the group exists by querying all local groups first and see if yours exists.

```
$computerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$adsi = [adsi]("WinNT://$computerName")
$localGroups = $adsi.children | Where-Object{$_.SchemaClassName -eq "Group"}
If($userGroup -notin $localGroups.Name){
    throw "Your group is in another castle."
}
```

or a variant

```
if(-not ($adsi.children | Where-Object{$_.SchemaClassName -eq "Group" -and $_.Name -eq $userGroup})){
    throw "Your group is in another castle."
}
```

Depending on where you are continuing with this code it might be advantageous to store this information once.